# NUC like PC for 64 GB RAM

Tags: memory, nuc

I'm very happy with Intel's NUC series. I don't do gaming but I need to run memory intensive applications (testing our SAP application + running SQL server). From the NUCs I saw, the maximum supported memory is 32 GB, which unfortunately is not sufficient.

I am looking for a

- 1 liter PC (if that's the right name; similar size as the NUC)
- min. 64 GB RAM supported
- 1 2.5" SSD / HDD slot
- HDMI connector
- graphics card for Full HD resolution (but only 2D tasks, so it needn't be a high performance 3D graphics card)
- Intel i7 processor

Price: if it comes without RAM and disk, ~500 € is ok.

Comment: You might take a look at Dell's OptiPlex series.

Comment: The Optiplex small form factor would be ok. However, it seems to come with 2x4 GB RAM and 500 GB disk which can't be removed from the configuration. I was unable to configure more and it remains unclear whether it supports 64 GB or not. I'd not like to pay for that RAM and that disk just to remove it later on.

Comment: I can build you a design that would work, but it would cost a lot more than 500 euros... most machines like what you're looking for are industrial machines, and they command a heft price premium that puts you right out of the market.

Comment: There don't seem to be too many options available. See this reddit https://www.reddit.com/r/sysadmin/comments/64x2sb/nuc_like_system_but_with_64gb_ram/